# What the technical term for factors of a number (via summation)?

Tags: summation, terminology, factoring

I know that 5 and 3 are factors of 15. Here `factors` are numbers whose multiplication gives 15.

What is the technical term for numbers whose `sum` (and not multiplication) is a given value?

i.e. technical term for following numbers

14 - 1 (sum is 15)

11 - 2 - 2 (sum is 15)

1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 .. 15times (sum is 15)

Comment: If order of terms is relevant, then you describe [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of the number.  If order of terms does not matter, then you describe [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of the number.  As for what to call the individual terms, "term" seems pretty generic and should suffice, otherwise "summand" refers to terms used in a generic sum.  "Parts" would work specifically for partitions, and from context may work fine for compositions as well.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, you might as well add it to existing answer or make new answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called the [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of a number.